# Memory Peak and Memory corruption using malloc and free

Tags: memory-management, malloc, free

I was recently asked in an interview to write to functions -

1. mymalloc which will return the peak value of the memory address allocated till now.
2. myfree which will tell if the user has done some operations which did memory corruption. eg. Program allocates memory address from location 101 to 200. If the program writes outside the boundaries ie 101 and 200, it is said to do memory corruption.

Note: These functions can use malloc and free internally to allocate and free memory.

Can someone please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

1. mymalloc could use the value of sbrk(0) to check the current location of the program heap break.
2. checking the corruption part is bit tricky. If you are just trying to make sure that the bytes after 200 are modified or not, then this can be achieved. Since every memory allocation has a header before the allocated buffer size which stores the size of the allocation, you can check the header of the next block i.e. header stored at location 201 to ensure that the program did cross its boundary to write into 201.